# Angular 9: How to get items from model.ts and show them in a dropdown list?

Tags: angular

I have `model.ts` like this:

```
export class Test001{
    id: number;
    item01: string;
    item02: string;
    item03: string;
    item04: string;
    item05: string;
}
```

I want to get the `item01, item02, ... item05`, and show them (not their values) into a dropdown list. Til now I have been making an extra `array = [item01, item02, ... item05]` in the `component.ts` manually. Is there method to read them directly from the `model.ts`?

Thanks for the advices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test Test001 is an object, so I believe what you want to display is their keys.

You can do `const keys = Object.keys(Test001);`

This will return an array to you, which you can loop through

Comment: Thank you. The two '))' s a typo?

Answer (score 1):

Use Object.keys it will return all the keys.

```
this.keys = Object.keys(Test001);
```

Comment: Thank you. The two '))' s a typo?